# jQuery - $('this'), loop or array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet I'm trying to work with whereby; I have a few products that I'm grabbing the source code, splitting it at the "?" and putting it in an array and then replacing "img.item-img" src with the new link.

However I'm not using a loop or $('this') to uniquely identify them apart from each other. so if i have for example three items, they all get the first's src code.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "img.item-img" ).each(function() {
   str = $("img.item-img").attr('src');


  arr = str.split("?");
  var new_link = arr[0];

  $("img.item-img").attr('src', new_link);
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what is your question? Because you said you don't use `$(this)`, but why don't you? (that's my question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the each callback function, you need to use $(this) to refer to the element you are currently looping over.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "img.item-img" ).each(function() {
   str = $(this).attr('src');


  arr = str.split("?");
  var new_link = arr[0];

  $(this).attr('src', new_link);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I just didn't understand how to correctly do it. I'm still fresh. but this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly identified, you need to use the `this` keyword as the single parameter for the `$()` function:

```
$('img.item-img').each(function() {
    var str      = $(this).attr('src'),
        arr      = str.split("?");

    $(this).attr('src', arr[0]);
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could use an anonymous function call in the `attr()` function:

```
$('img.item-img').attr('src', function() {  
    var arr = $(this).attr('src').split('?');
    return arr[0];
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3jn7e7de/) (of anonymous function return)